# How to store _attr key values in an array using php?

Tags: php, xml

I have parsed my xml into array using xml2array.php.
It gave array like

```
Array(
 [HotelImage] => Array
 (
      [0] => Array
      (
      )

      [1] => Array
      (
      )

      [0_attr] => Array
      (
           [Type] => Bar/Lounge
           [URL] => http://images.gta-travel.com/HH/Images/SA/ELS/ELS-HOL1-11.jpg
      )

      [1_attr] => Array
      (
           [Type] => Lobby
           [URL] => http://images.gta-travel.com/HH/Images/SA/ELS/ELS-HOL1-8.jpg
      )

      [2] => Array
      (
      )

      [2_attr] => Array
      (
           [Type] => Exterior
           [URL] => http://images.gta-travel.com/HH/Images/SA/ELS/ELS-HOL1-1.jpg
      )

      [3] => Array
      (
      )

      [3_attr] => Array
      (
           [Type] => Recreational Facilities
           [URL] => http://images.gta-travel.com/HH/Images/SA/ELS/ELS-HOL1-12.jpg
      )

     )
)
```

how can i store all _attr key values in a separate array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// this may cause a dereference error.. if it does just run array_keys
// and stro it in a sperate var that is then passed to preg_grep
$attrKeys = preg_grep('#\d+_attr#', array_keys($xmlArray));
$attrKeys = array_flip($attrKeys);
$attributes = array_intersect_key($xmlArray, $attrKeys);
$tags = array_diff_key($xmlArray, $attributes);
```

Comment: error: Call to undefined function array_intersect_keys() in D:\xampp\htdocs\chcf\coding\EmptyPHP.php on line 7

Comment: sorry should be `key` on both functions... updating answer.

Comment: How to replace all _attr keys into 0

Comment: can you post an exmaple of the output you want as well as the original array?